# How to save a number to a variable and then output that value?

Tags: bash, variables

I want to use `grep` to count the number of `W` occurrences in the `file.txt`, save it as the variable `WATER_NUMBER`. Then append that number to the end of `file.txt`.

Following [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash),

I tried

```
#!/bin/bash -l
WATER_NUMBER="$(grep -c W file.txt)"
sed -i -e '$a\"${WATER_NUMBER}"' file.txt
```

but I got `"${WATER_NUMBER}"` printed out, instead of the number. Can I ask how to modify it?

Comment: A variable assignment cannot have spaces around the `=`.

Comment: I have removed the spaces, but still the same.

Comment: Try `sed '$ a\'$WATER_NUMBER file.txt`

Comment: Ore try: `echo $WATER_NUMBER >> file.txt` The double `>` appends to the file.

Comment: yes, it works! could you please post your answer? and include the `-i -e` in your answer. @StefanHamcke

Comment: By the way, here you can find a nice tutorial on sed, covering all of this: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/sed.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command

```
sed -i '$a\"${WATER_NUMBER}"' file.txt
```

will simply add the line `"${WATER_NUMBER}"` at the end of the file. You could try

```
sed -i "$ a\$WATER_NUMBER" file.txt
```

but this will still add the line `$WATER_NUMBER`. The problem is that the variable WATER_NUMBER is not expanded in the sed script. In order to pass its value to sed, place it outside the quoting, like this

```
sed -i '$ a\'$WATER_NUMBER file.txt
```

**Edit:** I actually wrote my answer yesterday without really thinking about the reason as to why the variable is not expanded. This morning I wondered why this is the case even though the variable is in double quotes as opposed to single quotes. The reason is actually just the coincidence that the `\` from the append command is in front of the `$` from the variable, thus escaping it. To prevent this, you need to escape the `\`. On the other hand, a backslash is actually not needed to separate the `a` from the line you want to add, hence

```
sed -i "$ a $WATER_NUMBER" file.txt
```

will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

How to save a number to a variable?

```
WATER_NUMBER=42
```

How to append the variable content to a file?

```
echo $WATER_NUMBER >> file.txt
```